# Como inserir ON DELETE e ON UPDATE

Tags: mysql, chave-estrangeira

Tenho uma estrutura de banco de dados `MySQL` pronta, mas o `ALTER TABLE` das `FOREIGN KEY's` não especificou configurações para `ON DELETE` e `ON UPDATE`. Como insiro essas configurações agora, com as tabelas e chaves já criadas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiramente você precisaria `Dropar` a sua `Foreign Key`.

```
ALTER TABLE [Nome da sua Tabela] DROP FOREIGN KEY [Nome da sua Foreign Key];
```

Depois você precisa alterar a `Tabela` adicionando sua chave `FK` com o `ON DELETE CASCADE`

```
ALTER TABLE TABELA_1 
  ADD CONSTRAINT FK_NOME_SUA_FK 
  FOREIGN KEY (NOME_DA_COLUNA_QUE_SERA_FK_NA_TABELA_1) 
  REFERENCES NOME_DA_TABELA_2(NOME_DA_COLUNA_ESTRANGEIRA_DA_TABELA_2) 
  ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Answer (score -4):

Para a primeira linha de comando utilize:

Alter Table "nome_da_sua_tabela" Drop Constraint "fk_constraindechaveestrangeira"